# pdb - No arguments printed using 'args'

Tags: python, pdb

Code:

```
import pdb

def fun():
    i = 100
    pdb.set_trace()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

Output:

```
$ python pdb_script.py
--Return--
> /home/h/CARDIO/WorkSpace/PDB/pdb_script.py(7)fun()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) a
(Pdb) a
(Pdb)
```

Shouldn't `i` be an argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should `i` be an argument when it is a variable?

```
(Pdb) whatis i
<type 'int'>
```

and...

```
(Pdb) args
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to accomplish this in Python 3 is by using the following line in pdb:

```py
{k: v for k,v in locals().items() if '__' not in k and 'pdb' not in k}
```

This will display all the local variables in a dictionary format, less the dunder (i.e. '__main__') and pdb derived ones.